# Feeling others thoughts

Tags: vipassana

Lately I have been catching others thoughts and feelings as I advance in meditation. Sometimes this affects me and it starts playing out in the middle of my work. Does this happen to others? How are you all handling it?

Comment: https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN35_23.html

Comment: Related: [Intuition in Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10688/19249)

Comment: Yes, this is why I can’t live in a place with shared walls like an apartment. Not Buddhist but look for empath protection mediation on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this many moons ago when i started meditation and spiritual seeking. I was young and didn't really know "my" path in life, as too was I very open minded while learning and experimenting with Buddhism and esoteric practices.

The word is called clairsentience. I think it is quite a common thing for people to experience. When you open your mind and heart to the world, others and existence you become more awake and less centre focused, so you generate compassion and empathy and genuinely feel the suffering and plight of you fellow sentient beings, which in turn makes you "feel" their feelings and "see" their thoughts.

I would expect it to pass with more inner strength and skill in meditation.
Try not to hold on and cling to it, they are just minor [siddhis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddhi) from meditation. Just focus on your own practices and don't concern yourself too much with the results as they can become a barrier as you cling on to your new discovered abilities.

Even in the more conventional understanding, as it is essentially extreme empathy. Having too much empathy can turn one into a weak person and having not any or enough can turn one mentally unwell, psychopaths do not have empath for eg.